# Adding subviews to navigation bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have noticed that both the first-party Apple apps and some third-party apps are able to have search filter chips nested INSIDE the navigation bar below the titles. I am trying to figure out how one would go about achieving this.

I've tried to achieve this using a `.toolbar` modifier however this doesn't achieve the desired result.

Would appreciate anyones input on how one could achieve the navigation bar layouts in the screenshots using SwiftUI. That is, a native look/feel navigation bar with search, large titles, small titles, and the tags/chips/filters, exactly the same as the GitHub screenshots.

### Github Collapsed Navigation

[image: Github]

### GitHub Expanded Navigation

[image: Github]

### GitHub Search Navigation

[image: GitHub]

### Similar AppStore Layout

[image: AppStore]

### Scroll Behaviour w/Chips/Tags (What I'd like to achieve)

[image: Animation]

Comment: Your question isnt specific, how do you want it to be?

Comment: Do you wanna achieve something like this? https://ibb.co/x2S9WMX

Comment: @Jack I’d like to achieve the filters/chips/tags being inside the navigation bar, under the title, the same way it appears in all three screenshots

Comment: Can you underline (circle) the part that you want and I will code it for you!

Comment: @Jack thanks that’d be much appreciated. I’ve updated the screenshots to show the exact layout I’d like to achieve. Essentially I am trying to get a navigation bar, with large title support, a search bar AND the filter chips all inside the nav bar.

Comment: Which one do you want, the first/second/third?

Comment: @Jack The first and second are the same screen. I’d like it to work for both large and normal title modes. Essentially I want to copy exactly what the GitHub app is doing. Realistically though, being able to copy any of them would be a great achievement in my eyes so I am happy to take any.

Comment: I know, wait 10 minutes and I will code it for you (example)!

Comment: is there a any solution at the moment?

Answer (score -1):

In the App Store app. I am assuming they are using modifier `.searchable(text: Binding<String>, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)` to show for example Search bar in the navigation bar. `displayMode .always` is there just so the Searchbar is not "folding in" while scrolling, but it is always "unfolded".

I hope my answer makes sense :)

Comment: I'm familiar with the search bar behaviour, the question pertains directly to the chips underneath the search bar.